# Configure bind on VPS to use domain name as nameserver of the same domain

Tags: linux, domain, bind, vps, nameserver

I'm trying to configure bind on a VPS to make `ns1.example.com` and `ns2.example.com` point to it (already done) and make it serve `example.com`.

I used webmin previously on the same machine, and webmin configured bind, and it worked. After some time I have to move to another panel, and now I can't make this work.

- On my domain panel, I have already configured `ns1.example.com` and
  `ns2.example.com` as "Child NS" with the IP of the VPS.
- I'm using bind on debian.
- The VPS name (which can't change for some reason that is not clear
  to me) is `example.serverdomain`.
- Just tested firewall, and it's open on port 53.
- I actually copied, 99% of the config files created by webmin, which used to work.

`/etc/bind/named.conf.local` file is:

```
zone "example.com" {
    type    master;
    file    "/etc/bind/db.example.com";
    allow-transfer {
        127.0.0.1;
        localnets;
    };
};
```

-

`/etc/bind/db.example.com` file is:

```
$ttl 1D
$ORIGIN example.com
@                       IN  SOA example.serverdomain. root.example.serverdomain.(
                            20051901    ;Serial
                            10800       ;Refresh
                            3600        ;Retry
                            604800      ;Expire
                            38400       ;Negative Cache TTL
                        )
@                       IN  NS  example.serverdomain.
example.com.            IN  NS  ns1.example.com.
example.com.            IN  NS  ns2.example.com.
example.com.            IN  A   51.222.30.103
www.example.com.        IN  A   51.222.30.103
ftp.example.com.        IN  A   51.222.30.103
localhost.example.com.  IN  A   127.0.0.1
mail.example.com.       IN  A   51.222.30.103
example.com.            IN  MX  5 mail.example.com.
```

I tested on intodns.com and I got this

> Mismatched NS records
>   WARNING: One or more of your nameservers did not return any of your NS records. Error
>
> DNS servers responded
>   ERROR: One or more of your nameservers did not respond: The ones that did not respond are: 51.222.30.103

So...
**What is wrong with the configuration?**

Comment: First, it seems you are using an arbitrary domain name you don't own in your question. Either use the actual domain, when possible, or replace it with an allowed domain like `example.com` ([RFC 6761](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6761)).

Comment: @EsaJokinen  Ok, I updated the question. :) Can you notice any problem in that configuration now?

Comment: Is `51.222.30.103` the actual IP address of this VPS? It's not answering to DNS queries at all. Maybe the BIND isn't running. Yes, I can notice multiple problems with your configuration. There's also a reason this couldn't be solved as you wish: you need at least two name servers, and they can't both be the same VPS.

Comment: Also, the zone does not have a A records for ns1.example.com or ns2.example.com which are required.

Comment: @EsaJokinen you should be right but I suspect a not insignificant number of small providers cheat with the 2 nameserver requirement - I recently acquired a hosting company that did just this. 1 VPS, CPanel, 2 IPs assigned to VPS.  The worst part is the sellers had 0 understanding.

Comment: However, we shouldn't advice against the IANA's [Technical requirements for authoritative name servers](https://www.iana.org/help/nameserver-requirements).

Comment: @EsaJokinen Even though I don't know many standards, I'm believe on working with good practices, just like you, so I agree with you about how things should be done. I knew about the 2 servers stuff (I know they suggest 3 to 7), and I plan to do it. But now I just got 1 IP, and I'm trying to work with that since I'm in a hurry and I'm sure that works (It worked before). Once it's running I'll take my time to do it more properly, that's for sure.

Comment: @davidgo Actually those A records fixed the problem for me, so if you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. :-)
Thank you, and also to Esa Jokinen for taking the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like this has.nothing to do with your DNS server.

When you have subdomain records for a parent domain you need glue records. These are entries in the root name servers hard coding those domains to IP addresses. It sounds like these need to be updated to make your DNS work - speak to your registrar about it, as this is not done on your name servers.

Comment: Sorry,  but what you have written above are not words I understand. Child NS is not, AFAIK a phrase with an accepted meaning.  If the domain records at the registrar were pointing to the old IP rather then the new one then yes, that is what I am talking about.Google "glue records"

Comment: I MARK THIS ANSWER AS ACCEPTED because you gave me the answer that worked correctly in YOUR FIRST COMMENT UNDER THE QUESTION. So you deserve the credit. :)

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that there are [Technical requirements for authoritative name servers](https://www.iana.org/help/nameserver-requirements). The current configuration problem that is preventing your name service to work is mentioned there, too:

> **Consistency between glue and authoritative data**
>
> For name servers that have IP addresses listed as glue, the IP
>   addresses must match the authoritative A and AAAA records for that
>   host.

You had added the necessary *glue records* to the parent zone through your registrar, but didn't have the correspondind `A` records on the zone itself, i.e. your zone was missing:

```
ns1.example.com.        IN  A   51.222.30.103
ns2.example.com.        IN  A   51.222.30.103
```

Now, there's another problem: both are pointing to the same server. That's not OK:

> **Minimum number of name servers**
>
> There must be at least two NS records listed in a delegation, and the
>   hosts must not resolve to the same IP address.
>
> **Network diversity**
>
> The name servers must be in at least two topologically separate
>   networks. A network is defined as an origin autonomous system in the
>   BGP routing table. The requirement is assessed through inspection of
>   views of the BGP routing table.

Both your registrar or the VPS provider could provide secondary name servers as a service. This should have been addressed before building own name services, but as your registar already allowed you to use the same IP address for both name servers, you still have time to fix this afterwards. Some registars do perform tests before allowing changing the name servers. (Back in good old days e.g. `.fi` authorities were very strict with this, and wrongly configured name servers could even have led to cancelling the domain altogether.)

Lastly, your `SOA` record has a problem, too. It should have the valid FQDN hostname of your *primary authoritative name server* (`MNAME`) and a working email address of the administrator responsible for this zone (`RNAME`), e.g. with `hostmaster@example.com`:

```
example.com. IN SOA ns1.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. 2020052000 10800 3600 604800 38400
```